# action as state in UML state diagram

Tags: uml, stateful, statechart, state-diagram

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6TFVzBW7oo) video a part of an UML state chart can be seen :

[image]

However, the "provide funds" state is an action. How does that make sense ?

Is it possible for a state to be an action (verb) ?

Should the "provide funds" action not be rather a transition ?

Would something like this below not make more sense ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Provide Funds` in this case is also a state with the same name as an action. So they are not identical. They just have the same name. Sometimes it's hard to avoid this situation. From the modeling perspective I would say this state is simply superfluous. You could do self-transitions from `Funds Available` while funds are `> 0` and simply exit when fund gets zero.

P.S. Oh, I see your last picture is exactly what I said :-)

1. *So basically the `[funds avail >$0]` transition gets automatically triggered after the Provide Funds action completes?*

   Yes and no. `[funds avail >$0]` is a guard. The trigger is `request fund`. This transition will only be performed if the guard won't block (so if money is available).

   *So this is some kind of a "transient" state?* So to say.
2. *Also, do I get it right that the state while providing funds is also called `Provide Funds` (not just the the action)? So a better name for the state would be : the state of the machine **while** providing funds ?*

   Exactly.

Comment: Thanks, 1) So basically the `[funds avail >$0]` transition gets automatically triggered after the `Provide Funds` **action** completes ? So this is some kind of a "transient" state ? 

2) Also, do I get it right that the state while providing funds is also called `Provide Funds` (not just the the action ) ? So a better name for the state would be : `the state of the machine *while* providing funds` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is just poor naming. It should be called "Providing Funds". That would make clear what happens in that state and the fact that it is a state.